# how to create a launcher for software installed inside root directory

Tags: 12.04

I am using ubuntu **12.04** 64bit.

how to create a launcher for a software installed inside root directory, when I login as a regular user account?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What is the software? Why is it installed in the root directory?

Comment: A source control software, AccuRev, it is installed there by default. I didn't mean to install there.

Comment: There are going to be several problems. You probably installed the software with root permissions and the program were to be install at your home path (and it would probably do so, if you didn't run the installation with root privileges). What if you remove the program from your root directory and try re-installing as simple user?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA Quickly browsing the installation documentation, I don't see that you are required to install as root. With that in mind, I'd recommend reinstalling as a non-root user unless you have a specific reason you need it installed as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! In terminal,

```
whereis <program name>
```

After that, it would show the path of this program.

For instance,

```
$ whereis vi
vi: /usr/bin/vi /usr/share/man/man1/vi.1.gz
```

Now, you can run it via above path.

If it need root permission, just add `sudo` to the front of the command.